# How to store one table to another table in lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table

```
result={{language="English"},{language="Fres"}}

Save={}

for i,v in pairs(result) do
    print("result table",v.language)
    Save["language"]=v.language
end


for i,v in pairs(Save) do
    print("save table",v.language)
end
```

**how to store one table to another table same order**

Comment: You're not saving the tables. You're not filling the `Save` table at all, because you only assign single "language" field to it.

Comment: Show the expected result, and results you're getting with your attempts.

Comment: Replace `Save["language"]=v.language` with `Save[i]={language=v.language}`

Answer (score 1):

you are over thinking this. you have a table full of tables and you want to save each table into the table Save. just use `table.insert`.

```
result={{language="English"},{language="Fres"}}

Save={}

for i,v in pairs(result) do
    print("result table",v.language)
    table.insert(Save, v)
end


for i,v in pairs(Save) do
    print("save table",v.language)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```lua
result = {{language="English"}, {language="Fres"}}                                      
Save = {} 
                                                                      
for k, v in pairs(result) do                                                    
   Save[k] = v                                                                               
end
```